# How could I write data hourly to files named by current hour with multiple processes?

Tags: c++, linux, logging, multiprocessing

I have to write some data to a file based on current hour in my server. For example, write data to a file named like `2015061117.txt`. And there is multiple processes write data to file simultaneously. How should I design my server to implement this? Do I need to use some synchronization api like pthread_mutex_lock?

Comment: If you use *processes* you can't use thread synchronization primitives, you have to use other [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple processes, or even multiple threads, to write to the same file simultaneously, then you need to synchronize them so only one process or thread write at a time.

My suggestion is to use a separate process or thread that handles all the logging, and the other processes/threads sends "messages" to the logging process/thread which then writes the messages in the order it receives them. Similar to the syslog system in Linux.